# Get all input fields and retain values inside text fields even after button submit using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have multiple input fields and random input names, what I want to achieve is get the data entered in the text fields but then on clicking on the submit button, the data entered will remain.

Sample code:

```
  for($i=0;$i<$count1;$i++) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random1.'" value=""/>';
  }

  for($j=0;$j<$count2;$j++) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random2.'" value=""/>';
  }

  for($k=0;$k<$count3;$k++) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random3.'" value=""/>';
  }
  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>'
```

The problem here is that I don't know what are the 'input names'. I want the values entered by user into this text fields remain. How would I do that? If you don't know what the 'input names' are?

Comment: Why have you got random input names? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: If $count1, $count2 or $count3 are anything other than 1, you will end up with inputs with the same name. This will make your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: $random1, $random2 and $random3 are not the same, they are always different. so regardless of what are $count1, $count2 or $count3 maybe there's a way to retain  the values entered after submit

Comment: This can be done, but what's the point? I mean, why? Is there a logic behind that? Also, how are count1, count2 and count3 defined?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use hidden inputs to keep tracks of the names? Like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count1;$i++) {
    $value=getValueFor("section1-$i");
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random1.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="section1-'.$i.'" value="'.$random1.'"/>';
}

for($j=0;$j<$count2;$j++) {
    $value=getValueFor("section2-$j");
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random2.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="section2-'.$j.'" value="'.$random2.'"/>';
}

for($k=0;$k<$count3;$k++) {
    $value=getValueFor("section3-$k");
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random3.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="section3-'.$k.'" value="'.$random3.'"/>';
}
```

where getValueFor should be a function which checks what you got from GET or POST. For example:

```
function getValueFor($x){
    $res = "";
        if (isset($_REQUEST[$x])){
            $name=$_REQUEST[$x];
            $res = $_REQUEST[$name];
        }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work :

```
if (isset($_POST['random'])) {
   foreach ($_POST['random'] as $key => $randomName) {
       ${"random" . $key . "value"} = $randomName;
   }
}

for($i=0;$i<$count1;$i++) {
                echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random1.'" value="'.$random1value.'"/>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="random[]" value="'.$random1.'"/>';
          }

          for($j=0;$j<$count2;$j++) {
                echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random2.'" value="'.$random2value.'"/>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="random[]" value="'.$random2.'"/>';
          }

          for($k=0;$k<$count3;$k++) {
                echo '<input type="text" name="'.$random3.'" value="'·$random3value.'"/>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="random[]" value="'.$random3.'"/>';
          }
          echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>'`enter code here`;
 }
```